# Web Service Schema given a java class

Tags: java, web-services, xsd

I am new to web service and I am exploring one particular idea regarding this topic.

Supposed I have a java class like below

```
public class Department{
    private int id;
    private String name
    private List<Employee> employees;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I want to create a Web Service method and I wanted it to expose the data
to follow a certain schema when I call this web service.  This will basically
be the SOAP response schema.

```
<department>
    <id />
    <name />
    <employees type="list">
        <employee>
            <emp_id />
            <name />
        </employee>
        .
        .
    </employees>
</department>
```

The web service method will just find a department given a department id input parameter.
The output should follow the schema above

```
@WebService
public class Service{
    @WebMethod
    public Department getDepartment(int id){
      //code
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: by schema , did you mean , you want to ignore `id` and `name` field of department?

Comment: @Jigar Thanks for the response but to answer your question, I wanted the SOAP response to include the id and name field plus a complex type of employee object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to annotate your POJO class with proper JAXB annotations.

Here is an example :

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Department {


    @XmlElement
    private Long id
    @XmlElement
    private String name 
    @XmlElement
    private List<Employee> employees;

    // +accessor methods

}
```

Also annotate your Employee class in the same manner.

And use

```
@WebService(name = "departmentServiceSOAP", targetNamespace = "/namespace")
@javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface DepartmentService {
    @WebMethod
    public Department getDepartment(Long id);
}
```

---

- [Reference](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/)