# Web services cross-languages parameter types

Tags: java, web-services, arguments, jax-ws

I am creating a web service. I want to know how do I declare parameter type and use it
as Java type is different for eg. date. I have written client to consume web services in Java which is working fine, but I want to know whether I can consume same web services using client written in some other language. I am giving you a code example of my web service:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class WiseQuoteServer {
    @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
    public String getQuote(String category) {
        if (category.equals("fun")) {
            return "5 is a sufficient approximation of infinity.";
        }
        if (category.equals("work")) {
            return "Remember to enjoy life, even during difficult situatons.";
        } else {
            return "Becoming a master is relatively easily. Do something well and then continue to do it for the next 20 years";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WiseQuoteServer server = new WiseQuoteServer();
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish(
                "http://localhost:9191/wisequotes", server);
    }
}
```

Comment: This wlil help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726550/web-service-schema-given-a-java-class/5726901#5726901

Answer (score 3):

Jigar is correct.  JAX-WS uses JAXB to convert parameters into XML.  JAXB has an extensive set of annotations that you can use to customize how the data is turned into XML.  Since the data is sent as XML almost any language can read/write to the service.  Furthermore, most languages have some kind of SOAP library available.

Comment: Sir From WSDl example i can see many things which is not there in this . I mean when i am running above program and typing  in firefox address i can see a wsdl file but it it also displaying message <b>This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.</b> How can I add style information